# how to overlap 2 div without moving the text of the first div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some text and another div with some hidden buttons behind the text div and move to the left when needed (anitmation).

The problem is that the text inside div is moved to the right to let the buttons div not overlap with the text.

Check here:
http://clip2net.com/s/2JYBV

How to make text of main text div not interact depending of the the width/size/position of the button div?

Comment: Post your working code and desired result screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.a {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin:50px 200px;
    background:#000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
}
.b {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    width:180px;
    height:290px;
    background:green;
    display:none;
}
.a:hover .b {
    display:block;
    /* left:-150px; */
}
```

You can use relative and absolute positioning of divs to fulfill your required task.

http://jsfiddle.net/G9Q25/

Comment: It works fine on your jsfiddle but i don't know why but when I add a position: absolute in my code, the div goes to upper left corner of the screen, it's not relative to the first div like in your jsfiddle.

Comment: ok, my "a" didn't had the relative position, in this case, the "b" div is relative to top/right. Thank you!

Comment: you have to make it `position:relative` to make the child div positioned relative to that parent one else it will be relative to document and hence will result as you said

Answer (score 0):

try giving a z-index to your button div 
z-index:2;

Comment: i tried with z index but the text is still moved to the right

Comment: did you give position to your divs???
    position: absolute;
    top: --pixeks from top--;
    left: --pixeks from left--;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your definition:

```
overflow:hidden;
```